# Does special relativity imply that time dilation is affected by an orientation of clocks?

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, time-dilation

Many texts about STR time dilation use as an example thought experiment with [2 mirror photon clock.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation#Simple_inference_of_velocity_time_dilation)
The conclusion of this experiment is: In a frame moving relative to the clock, they will appear to be running more slowly.
As I understand it, this is just a visual effect, it doesn't mean that processes in the system with clocks are affected by someone observing it from moving frame.
I can't imagine any other interpretation of this, cause this would result in all sorts of paradoxes, like what if there are 3 clocks oriented: parallel, perpendicular and at 45 degree relative to direction of moving frame. If you visualise light path from moving frame perspective like it is done in wiki link above, and do analogical interpretation, this would imply that some of the 3 clocks in same frame are running slower and some are faster, depending on orientation.
[image: 3 mirror clocks at different orientations]

According to the same wiki page this time dilations are not just visual effect and do change behavior of objects, here is a quote from 2nd paragraph:

> Such time dilation has been repeatedly demonstrated, for instance by small disparities in a pair of atomic clocks after one of them is sent on a space trip, or by clocks on the Space Shuttle running slightly slower than reference clocks on Earth, or clocks on GPS and Galileo satellites running slightly faster.

So if we continue our analogy, we can take 4 pairs of atomic clocks, and send 3 of them on a space trip oriented differently, we would get different time results on them.

We can even continue this absurd, and remind "twins paradox", and conclude that the one that was perpendicular to moving frame would become older....

Comment: see my answer here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/276603/4993

Comment: @WillO Thanks, I read it, need some time to chew on it, your idea barely fits my mind,

Comment: @WillO Your answer there is unclear, because it does not explain why "the length of the light-beam's round-trip journey" in the direction of the flight would result in the same time dilation. For example, how would this length involve a square root? The correct answer is that the length of the light clock oriented in the direction of the flight is contracted due to the length contraction effect of Special Relativity. It is for this reason the clock period does not depend on the angle.

Comment: @AlexBurtsev STR is nothing but a hyperbolic geometry in the Minkowski space. As such it is mathematically consistent. Any "paradoxes" in it are simply lack of understanding. It can be faulted no more than the Euclidean geometry in the Euclidean space. The interesting stuff begins only when space is non-trivial. For example, in a closed cylindrical universe two twins flying in the opposite directions see each other's time dilated, but meet after a half a circle at the same age (due to symmetry).

Comment: @safesphere I'm reading right now what Einstein himself wrote in 1905, http://hermes.ffn.ub.es/luisnavarro/nuevo_maletin/Einstein_1905_relativity.pdf and it looks different from how it is interpretated nowdays. He wrote:  "The laws by which the states of physical systems undergo change are not affected, whether these changes of state be referred to the one or the other of two systems of co-ordinates in uniform translatory motion." However lots of people say time dilations do change how systems undergo change.

Comment: @AlexBurtsev:  Lots of people say all kinds of crazy things on the Internet.   It's best to stick to  ignore most of them.  Your quote from Einstein is the basis of relativity,  both as he understood it and as it is understood today (at least by everyone who understands it).  If you find a source that says otherwise, it is almost surely written by a crank.

Comment: @safesphere:  *The correct answer is that the length of the light clock oriented in the direction of the flight is contracted due to the length contraction effect of Special Relativity. It is for this reason the clock period does not depend on the angle.* No, that's exactly backward.  The reason the clock period doesn't depend on the angle is the principle of relativity (as quoted from Einstein in Alex Burtsev's comment).  (If it did depend on the angle, you'd know who was moving.)  From this, one derives the length contraction.

Comment: @AlexBurtsev You are correct that time dilation does not affect the system itself, but it affects the way the system looks to other observers. For example, decaying particles appear to live longer when they move fast. Their decay time is still the same in their own frame, but to us they appear to live longer, because we see their time dilated. Time dilation and length contraction are simply projections in the hyperbolic geometry. A projection is how an object appears to others, it does not change the object itself. The effects are real though, as faster moving muons do live longer.

Comment: @WillO I respectfully disagree. My point is that your answer overlooked length contraction and did not have any math to show how different orientations of clocks work in the hyperbolic geometry of the Minkowski space. Your answer was essentially based on faith that Relativity says so and therefore it must be do. You provided no proof that it is indeed so. Furthermore, in the current question Alex challenges the principle of relativity as suspectedly invorrect. So your answer that it is so because Relativity says so is not helpful. You need to show why and how exactly Relativity still stands.

Comment: @safesphere:  You are taking it as given that allowable transformations must preserve the geometry of Minkowski space.  I am taking it as given that Einstein's postulates hold.   These are essentially equivalent starting points.  One can derive the length contraction in the language of geometry or in the language of the Einstein postulates; either way, the reasoning is the same (though expressed differently).  If I'm saying "this is so because relativity says so", you are saying "this is so because preservation of the metric says so" ---- but then we are saying the same thing.

Comment: @WillO Agreed that the postulates are virtually equivalent to the Minkowski metric, but the question is to show the clock independence of the angle. The answer "because it is relative" states that *somehow* relativity should ensure this, but does not explain *how* it works out in the remote frame and doesn't even suggest that it is due to the length contraction. A good answer should show the way the math works out. This is why my post was only a comment. Also, respectfully, you should use a constructive criticism as an opportunity to improve instead of fighting that you are always right :)

Comment: @safesphere:  I think I have a pretty track strong record of accepting constructive criticisms when I'm wrong, but in this case you've failed to convince me.  You say the independence of the angle is due to the length contraction.   I prefer to say exactly the opposite:  The length contraction is due to the independence of the angle (which in turn is due to relativity).   I like my way better, because yours raises the question:  Then what is the length contraction due to?   And the answer is still going to come back to:  relativity, just as mine does.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answer to the title question: **absolutely not**.

---

### Experimental Touchstone

Before we explain in detail, let's begin by noticing that the Michelson-Morley interferometric experiment *explicitly* tests if orientation affects the clocking behavior of a there-and-back light path. And quite famously the answer is "no". This must be true for any inertial observer.<sup>1</sup>

So why do all the introductory materials use a transverse clock?

It's actually a good question and the answer (at least beyond *"Well, that's what Einstein did!"*), requires taking a close look at the way the explanation would work with a longitudinal clock.

### What *is* Going on, Then?

The **short version** is easy: *because the longitudinal light clock is affected by length contractions as well as time dilation*.<sup>2</sup> And then it follows that from a didactic point of view you want to develop one of the rules (time dilation or length contraction) first, and address the second one separately rather than trying to deal with them at the same time. That makes the transverse clock preferable for intorducing relativity.

To show this the long way we'll imagine two basically identical light-reflection clocks $\mathbb{c}$ and $\mathbb{C}$, where $\mathbb{c}$ is the traditional transverse clock and $\mathbb{C}$ is aligned longitudinally.<sup>3</sup> In their rest frame $S$, each clock has length $l = L$, and consequently identical periods $p = 2l/c$ and $P = 2L/c$. We then consider the behavior of the clocks as observed in frame $S'$ moving at speed $-v$ along the length of $\mathbb{C}$ with respect to $S$.

#### Transverse case

The analysis of the period of $p'$ of the transverse clock is the traditional one: the time required to complete the trip (out and back) is
\begin{align}
p' 
&= \frac{\sqrt{(2l)^2 + (vp')^2}}{c}\\
&= \sqrt{\left(\frac{2l}{c}\right)^2 + \left(\beta p'\right)^2} \\
&= p \sqrt{1 + \left( \beta \frac{p'}{p}\right)^2}  \;,
\end{align}
so that
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{p'}{p} \right)^2
&= 1 + \left(\beta \frac{p'}{p}\right)^2\\
\frac{p'}{p} 
&= \left(1 - \beta^2 \right)^{-1/2} \\
&= \gamma\;.
\end{align}

#### Longitudinal case

To find the period $P'$ of the longitudinal clock we have to do a bit more figuring. The elapsed time $T_f$ for the forward going half of the journey is
$$ T_f' = \frac{L' + v T_f'}{c} \;,$$
and for the backward going half of the journey the time $T_b$ required is
$$ T_b' = \frac{L' - v T_b'}{c} \;.$$
After a little figuring we get the period as
\begin{align}
P' 
&= \frac{L'}{c(1 - \beta)} + \frac{L'}{c(1 + \beta)}\\
&= \frac{2L'}{c(1 - \beta^2)} .
\end{align}
Now, if $L' = L$ this would lead to
$$ \frac{P'}{P} = \left( 1 - \beta^2 \right)^{-1} = \gamma^2 \;, \tag{wrong!}$$
meaning the clocks would not agree, but as we said before Michelson-Morley style of experiments rule that out, so $L'$ *must* not be the same as $L$. To get the agreement we must have it is required that
$$ \frac{L'}{L} = \left(1 - \beta^2 \right)^{1/2} \;,$$
the usual expression for length contraction.

### Better Way

All that work is, quite frankly, nasty, and I would recommend a geometry first approach as a better alternative to Einstein's version. Get Takeuchi's book, it's worth the money.

---

<sup>1</sup> Because it tells us that two clocks set with their emit/receive ends coincident that beat in time with one another will *still* beat in time with one another when you swing them around. It doesn't mean that all observer will agree on the frequency of the clocks, just that the two clocks agree.

<sup>2</sup> That's what Lorentz-Fitzgerald contraction is all about after-all: fixing up the classical theory to match the Michelson-Morley results.

<sup>3</sup> We'll continue to use lower case for quantities related to the transverse clock and capitals for quantities related to the longitudinal clock throughout.

Answer (score 1):

Consider 4 identically constructed light-clocks of various orientations that have the same mirror separation when they are at rest. For convenience, let's arrange them in a circle, each with one mirror at a common point. In the rest frame, if the initial signals are emitted by the center at the same event, the reflections off the mirrors are received by the center at the same event.

When this circular light clock is set in uniform motion, the variously-oriented light clocks experience length-contractions... [the circular light clock looks like an ellipse in the lab frame].. in such a way that the reflections are still received by the center at the same event... in accord with the principle of relativity.

Here is a frame from my video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AXx3CB80rAk to motivate Length Contraction.
[image: VPT-circularLightClock-LengthContraction]

Here is a frame from my video ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tIZeqRn7cmI ) of an animated spacetime diagram of a ticking circular light-clock. 
[image: VPT-circularLightClock-TimeDilation]

In this video ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NqjAOyGR82s ), I apply this to demonstrate the Clock Effect (related to the Twin Paradox).
[image: VPT-circularLightClock-ClockEffect]

Some further details are available in my paper:
"Visualizing proper-time in Special Relativity"
 
Physics Teacher (Indian Physical Society), v46 (4), pp. 132-143 (October-December 2004)
https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0505134

Answer (score 1):

I would resolve this problem for any arbitrary angle of the light clock inclination to show that the time dilation is independent of the light clock's orientation. If the clock is inclined at an angle $\theta^\prime$ in its rest frame, this angle changes into $\theta$ from the viewpoint of the lab observer WRT whom the light clock moves at $v$ so that we have: [See the attached Figure.]

[image: Einstein's Oblique Light Clock]

$$\cos\theta'=\frac{x'}{L'}\space and \space \cos\theta=\frac{\alpha x'}{L} \tag{1&2}$$

Recall that $\alpha$ is the reciprocal of the Lorentz factor. Moreover, we have:

$$\tan\theta'=\frac{y'}{x'}\space and \space \tan\theta=\frac{y'}{\alpha x'} \tag{3&4}$$

Eqs. (1&2) and Eqs. (3&4) repectively imply:

$$\frac{\cos\theta'}{\cos\theta}=\frac{L}{\alpha L'} \space and \space \frac{\tan\theta'}{\tan\theta}=\alpha \tag{5&6}$$

Eqs. (5&6) yield:

$$\frac{L}{L'}=\frac{\alpha/\cos\theta}{\sqrt{1+\alpha^2\tan^2\theta}}=\frac{c\alpha}{\sqrt{c^2-v^2\sin^2\theta}} \tag{7}$$

Now, using the cosines law for $\Delta ABC$, we get:

$$c^2t_1^2=v^2t_1^2+L^2-2vt_1L\cos(\pi-\theta) \rightarrow $$

$$t_1=\frac{v\cos\theta+\sqrt{c^2-v^2\sin^2\theta}}{c^2-v^2}L \tag{8}$$

using the cosines law for $\Delta BCD$, we finally get:

$$c^2t_2^2=v^2t_2^2+L^2-2vt_2L\cos\theta \rightarrow $$

$$t_2=\frac{-v\cos\theta+\sqrt{c^2-v^2\sin^2\theta}}{c^2-v^2}L \tag{9}$$

For $t=t_1+t_2$, we have:

$$t=\frac{2L\sqrt{c^2-v^2\sin^2\theta}}{c^2-v^2}\tag{10}$$

As we know the time measured by the observer in the light clock's rest frame is $t^\prime=2L'/c$, thus we can write:

$$\frac{t}{t'}=\frac{c\sqrt{c^2-v^2\sin^2\theta}}{c^2-v^2}\frac{L}{L'} \tag{11}$$

Substituting Eq. (7) into Eq. (11), we get:

$$\frac{t}{t'}=\frac{1}{\alpha} \tag{12}$$

Therefore, the time dilation is independent of the light clock's orientation.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer! in solving L/L', where did the cos(theta ') go?

Comment: @GalaxyLimits Not at all. The proof is left to the student as an exercise! ;)